# How could the Marines catch Zoro?

Tags: one-piece

The first time Luffy met Zoro, Zoro got caught by the Marines because [he killed Helmeppo's pet wolf](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Helmeppo#History).

[image]

He was already strong at that time, he could easily defeat Morgan, a Marine Captain there. Had he deliberately made himself get caught? Why did he do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think nothing is mentioned in the manga about this. According to the anime ([second episode](http://watchonepiece.us/one-piece-episode-2-english-sub/)), Zoro was blackmailed by Helmeppo to surrender for 1 month otherwise he will ask his father to execute the family. Zoro agrees on the condition that the family will not be harmed.

Answer (score 4):

He deliberately got caught in order to save the little girl who was threatened by Helmeppo with a gun.

Comment: Where in the manga or anime was this explained?

Comment: In anime second episode.